# Why does the C++ 'int arr[n];' such that n is variable works in one environment and doesn't work in another?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

When I type:

```
int n; 
cin >> n; 
int a[n];
```

It works on VS code but doesn't work on Visual Studio.

I expected it not to work at all because of memory-related stuff.

So, any explanation why it does work on VS code ?

Comment: Editor doesn’t matter, it’s about the compiler. It’s not standard feature so there’s no requirement for it to work. Some compilers allow it

Comment: What does "works on VS code" mean?  VS Code is an editor, not a compiler.

Comment: Just don't do it. It's not standard C++. If you need runtime-sized arrays, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @jamesdlin 
I checked compiler settings in both environment. It's identical!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[n]` is variable-length array (VLA) which is a C99 feature.  It is not a C++ feature.  Some C++ compilers, never the less, accept the syntax as a compiler extension.

Comment: Does the memory allocated for the array in our case belongs to stack or heap? If heap, can a memory leak happens as expected? should I delete it ?

Comment: It depends on the compiler.  gcc allocates it on the stack and why it's dangerous.  You don't need to deallocate it.